# Link from Alfresco Share wiki to directory in Alfresco Repository

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

How to create a link in an Alfresco Share wiki page to a directory in the Alfresco Repository?

Comment: Can you not just get the URL of the document library page with for that directory, then link to that as normal?

Comment: I hoped there would be a solution with share wiki syntax. Otherwise I end up adding html. (not very user friendly, different styling, etc.)

Comment: The Share wiki was written by some contractors without a lot of supervision, and therefore has some rather *interesting* features and missing parts... It probably wouldn't be that much work to add this in though, if you had a bit of time to work + contribute an enhancement!

Comment: I've done that quite often just copy the url from your document/folder and paste it as an html link in your wiki and it works quite good. You coud look into extending the TinyMCE Editor which is uses to write the HTML. Alfresco has already made a custom button to insert Image Files, so you can make you own.

Comment: @Gagravarr: what happened to your Alfresco blog? It would be interesting to get some insight on just how 'open source' they actually are.

Comment: @EML I haven't worked for Alfresco for over a decade now, I suspect the blog died in one of the many rebrands over that time....

Answer (score 0):

In Share->Document Library, click on the item menu "View Details" for the directory you want to link to, and copy the link under "Copy this link to share the current page" in the clipboard.
Edit your wiki page and "insert/edit link" ; paste the clipboard in the field "URL link".